# JSF Life Cycle (Validation)

Tags: java, validation, jsf, lifecycle

I have a JSF page with an element which has attribute of `required=true` and `disabled`, I want to trigger the validation on that specific element. What I did is submitting it using `<h:commandButton>`, on the onclick event, I remove the `disabled` attribute, but after the page renders the validation error doesnt show up. Anyone knows why?

```
<h:inputText id="myInput" required="true" disabled="disabled" />
<h:commandButton id="saveButton" action="#{myBean.saveDetail}">

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('saveButton').onclick = function() {
     document.getElementById('myInput').removeAttribute('disabled');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: the inputtext contains any value?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems here:

1.The disabled attribute should be boolean on the inputText.

2.Disabled attribute means:

> Flag indicating that this element must
>   never receive focus or be included in
>   a subsequent submit.

So no validators will run on it.

3.You can't change the `h:inputText`'s disabled attribute on the client side, it would be a security problem in JSF if you could.